# How to get last record in every week in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have data in a table where I may or may not have the records for every day. I need to get last 6 weeks data, where I require only last record in every week.

Suppose if today is 24th, I need to get the last record from 18th to 24th and 11th to 17th and so on until 6 weeks.

This query gives all the 6 weeks records, but I need last record in every week.

```
SELECT snap.created_at
FROM snapshots snap
WHERE snap.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Example:

CREATED_AT

2017-03-23 11:20:30

2017-03-23 10:40:21

2017-03-21 09:58:42

2017-03-03 15:02:20

2017-03-02 14:41:49

2017-02-23 10:59:26

2017-02-22 15:59:53

2017-02-21 11:08:57

2017-02-21 10:43:24

2017-02-18 01:37:33

2017-02-11 01:38:29

Output:

(1st week) 2017-02-11 - 2017-02-17 = **2017-02-11 01:38:29**

(2nd week) 2017-02-18 - 2017-02-24 = **2017-02-23 10:59:26**

(3rd week) 2017-02-25 - 2017-03-03 = **2017-03-03 15:02:20**

(4th week) 2017-03-04 - 2017-03-10 = **2017-03-03 15:02:20** (as there are no records in this week, need to show the latest record from the last week)

(5th week) 2017-03-11 - 2017-03-17 = **2017-03-03 15:02:20** (as there are no records in this week, need to show the latest record from the last week)

(6th week) 2017-03-18 - 2017-03-24 = **2017-03-23 11:20:30**

Comment: You mean subtract date from now to 6 that would be the start of first week moving backward? just include a sample data here and expected result

Comment: Are you working MYSQL or SQL?

Comment: write a select query with between condition like select * from table where col_Date between DATEDIFF(GETDATE() -6,'DAYS') AND GETDATE()

Comment: Do you have autoincrement id field? what last record do you need min(created_at) or max(created_at) for every week?

Comment: I need max(created_at)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select datepart(wk, datecolumn), max(datecolumn) from yourtable
where (datediff(wk,datecolumn,getdate())) < 6
group by datepart(wk, datecolumn)
order by 2 desc
```